# IIS web application Error 401.2 through IP address

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-3.5, http-status-code-401

I have a web application on my local computer on a domain that works on IIS 7.5. When accessing this web app through localhost it works fine, but if I try using my IP address instead, It asks for my credentials and when I don't enter them, I get Error 401.2.

[image]

I already have Annonymous access and windows authentication enabled.[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work. Instead of using my IP address to access the web app, I used my computer name.